# Just the homepage title is not rendering in Express .render() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

My syntax is correct for Jade because the `title= title` shows in my other pages and I'm using a `layout.jade` file.  But for some reason the title is not rendering JUST for the homepage

layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/grid.css')
  body
    .container
        h1= title
        div.main-nav
    block content
```

index.jade

```
 extends layout

 block content

    p Welcome to the angular app
```

snippet of controller for index (THIS ONE IS NOT RENDERING TITLE)

```
app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.render('index', {title: 'Home'});

});
```

snippet of controller for other page (THIS WORKS)

```
app.get('/angularIndex', function(request, response){
    response.render('angular/angularIndex', {title: 'AngularJS App'});

});
```

NOTE:  the layout renders.  It's just the homepage.  Anyone run into this issue?  It's doing this when starting app with `nodemon` and `npm start`

Comment: Please post your index.jade file

Comment: EDIT - added index.jade

Comment: And what is content of `angular/angularIndex`? Is it similar to `index`?

Comment: @PashaRumkin yes, it's the index

Comment: Have you tried using another variable name for the title - one that is not reserved by the pug language (e.g. `pageTitle`)?

Comment: Does the compiled HTML have anything in its title?